# Reordenar una sola columna - SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta de SQL que me genera una tabla similar a la que muestro.

```
select * from mi_tabla order by secuencia desc
```

| secuencia | nombre | apellido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Juan | Arboleda |
| 2 | Luis | Arreaga |
| 1 | Pedro | Castro |

Necesito implementar un algoritmo para reorganizar el resultado para reordenar solo la columna secuencia de forma ascendente

| secuencia | nombre | apellido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | Arboleda |
| 2 | Luis | Arreaga |
| 3 | Pedro | Castro |

He intentado crear una tabla temporal y en ella re organizar los números de secuencia pero en la actualizacion me da un error pues obviamente se esta tomando una lista y no un valor unico

```
create table auxiliar (secuencia int null)
insert into auxiliar (select secuencia from mi_tabla order by secuencia desc)
update mi_tabla set secuencia = (select secuencia from mi_tabla)
```

Alguna idea para implementar este reordenamiento

Comment: te refieres a hacer lo mismo que haces cuando ordenas de manera descendente mediante el campo secuencia pero del contrario?? si es el caso solo prueba la misma consulta que tienes y en ves de colocar desc al final coloca asc. Si se comporta como esperas, solo es que lo hagas con la consulta real.

Comment: No, no funcionaria, pues con la sentencia que mencionas, si bien la columna secuencia se organizaria como se desea, el resto de las columnas perderia el orden, fijate que en la descripcion de la pregunta, solo cambia la columna secuencia, el resto de columnas se necesita que se mantengan tal cual la consulta original

Comment: Realmente no se desorganizan, el tema es que los demás datos se mueven de posisión de acorde a donde quede el respectivo registro al que le haces el order by. Si a la persona a le pertenece la secuencia 1, y a la persona b la secuencia 2. No puedes esperar que al aplicarle el order by al campo secuencia solo se mueva el campo secuencia y el resto de la información se quede como quieres. Esto sería un error ya que se asociarían campos que no son los correspondientes. Mejor di que es lo que realmente deseas hacer que te lleva a pensar modificar la consulta así.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero la secuencia no es un dato primario ni de identificacion del registro

Comment: Pero van a quedar asociados mal los datos, no importa si es primario o no, si un registro me trae a pepito pérez, el otro a juan garcía. si ordenamos solo por el apellido sin que se muevan los otros datos, ps podría quedar pepito garcía y juan pérez. Cosa que no es verdad. A eso me refiero

Comment: El caso real de este ejemplo esta alrededor de un tema de reportes de alta frecuenia sin mayor dinamismo (se imprime el resultado por varios usuarios, pero la informacion cambia muy pocas veces), necesitamos usar el campo secuencia para mostrar un listado de personas en un orden especifico ya definido en reemplazo de hacer una gran query con multiples ordenamientos cada vez que se solicite el reporte.

Comment: ¿Con cuál motor de base de datos?

Comment: Cual es tu gestor de base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es reenumerar la filas de tu consulta. Quizas no es exactamente lo que estás buscando.

No se que motor de base de datos (RDBMS) estás utilizando.

Por ejemplo en MySql (versión >= 8.0) podrías hacerlo así:

Enumera utilizando números enteros consecutivos desde el 1 hasta n (siendo n el total de registros).

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS secuencia,
       nombre,
       apellido
FROM mi_tabla;
```

Al reenumerar podrías ordenar por apellido y nombre:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY apellido, nombre) AS secuencia,
       nombre,
       apellido
FROM mi_tabla;
```

Resultado (según datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| secuencia | nombre | apellido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | Arboleda |
| 2 | Luis | Arreaga |
| 3 | Pedro | Castro |

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas agregar un ordenamiento, hace lo siguiente, crea una tabla temporal y le pones un identity.

create table #temporal (
id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),
secuencia int,
nombre varchar(30),
apellido varchar(30)
);

insert into #temporal ( secuencia, nombre, apellido)
select secuencia, nombre, apellido
from mi_tabla order by secuencia desc

select id_num as secuencia, nombre, apellido
from #temporal

Esto podrías hacer, para generar un ordenamiento con tabla temporal.

Comment: pero el ordenamiento que implementas, ordena la secuencia, pero cambia la posición de los demás campos. Lo que quieren hacer es modificar el orden de la secuencia sin alterar el como se encuentran organizados el resto de los datos. Así que la respuesta que propónes no es lo apropiado en este caso